# Can I change the encoding of the content of a file to show Chinese characters?

Tags: encoding

I have a file containing contents(Unicode escape string in specific) like this:

```
title=\"\u5e2e\u4e0a\u5934\u6761\">\u5e2e\u4e0a\u5934\u6761<\/a><\/li>\n
```

in my working Vim window and want to show it as Chinese.

This is the output of the locale command in my terminal:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF•8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF•8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF•8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF•8
LC_COLLATE=“en_US.UTF-8”
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF•8
LC_MESSAGES=“en_US.UTF-8”
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF•8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF•8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF•8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF•8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF•8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF•8
LC_ALL=
```

And the OS I use is Ubuntu 14.04.

I know I can print the Chinese characters using Python:

```
print u"\u5e2e\u4e0a\u5934\u6761".encode('utf-8')
# encode the unicode string to utf-8 string which matches the terminal encoding. 
# If I write the result to a file I can see Chinese characters if I open it by vim.
```

Is there a way for me to make vim to show the Chinese characters? Can I do this using vimscript inside vim with a toggle to switch between these two encoding systems if possible?

Aware that I can realize the function with the thoughts above I want to know if there is existing scripts, which will prevent me recreating wheals.

Comment: `:set fileencoding=utf8` or `:set encoding=utf8` will do :)

Comment: @SibiCoder No, it seems it doesn't work. I've set it in vimrc and reopen it but nothing different happended; I encoded the file using Python to utf-8 and write it to a new file with the your setting in vimrc but it also doesn't work if I open the new file. I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: It looks like you're using literal escaped unicode strings.  That's not a problem with text encoding.  I posted an answer that will convert the text to unicode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like this to convert to Unicode:

```
%s/\%(\\u\x\+\)\+/\=eval('"'.submatch(0).'"')/g
```

And back:

```
%s/[^\x00-\x7f]/\=printf('\u%x', char2nr(submatch(0)))/g
```

As a naive toggle command:

```
function! s:toggle_unicode(line1, line2) abort
  if search('\\u\x\+', 'n')
    execute a:line1.','.a:line2.'s/\%(\\u\x\+\)\+/\=eval(''"''.submatch(0).''"'')/g'
  else
    execute a:line1.','.a:line2.'s/[^\x00-\x7f]/\=printf(''\u%x'', char2nr(submatch(0)))/g'
  endif
endfunction

command! -range=% UnicodeToggle call s:toggle_unicode(<line1>, <line2>)
```